Scala 3.5.0 unreachable case which was working with 3.4.2
I'm using Scala 3.5.0 with these compiler options:
    -language:strictEquality
    -Yexplicit-nulls
    -Wsafe-init
    -explain
    -indent
    -new-syntax
    -Xfatal-warnings
    -Wunused:all
    -Wvalue-discard
    -Wnonunit-statement
    -Xcheck-macros
    -source future

The following code gives a (fatal) warning about case _ => being unreachable:
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath

class testingCode:
  def process(t: TreeSelectionEvent) =
    val n = t.getNewLeadSelectionPath
    n match
      case tp: TreePath =>
      case _ =>

If I change n match with (n: TreePath | Null) match everything works fine.
I'm convinced this wasn't happening with Scala 3.4.2 (I don't know about 3.4.3) and in any case if I refer to https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/experimental/explicit-nulls.html I can't understand why it complains about an unreachable case. If I open TreeSelectionEvent.java it's clear that n can be Null.
Unless this is a Scala bug I don't understand why it's happening and would love some insight.

Note that AFAIK explicit-nulls is experimental and soon to be deprecated. I would advice not relying too much on it.

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I see, probably that's the reason then. A pity, I found it very useful. Hopefully they are replacing it with something even better...
